# how to call call another function in jquery after sliding is over?

Tags: jquery, function, toggle, call, slide

How do I call an other function using jquery , I have tried all methods and all failed,
I have an example using the slide function of jquery api script I need to call a function afer the sliding is over but i am not able to execute the simple function `complete()`

```
 <html>
    <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    <script> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $(".flip").click(function(){
        $("#panel").slideToggle(["slow"][,complete]); // i need to call the complete function

           function complete(){alert("hello");}
      });
    });
    </script>

    <style type="text/css"> 
    #panel,.flip
    {
    padding:5px;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:#e5eecc;
    border:solid 1px #c3c3c3;
    }
    #panel
    {
    padding:50px;
    display:none;
    }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div class="flip">Click to slide the panel down or up</div>
    <div id="panel">Hello world!</div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

I have used this example from w3schools

http://w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_slide_toggle

Answer (score 1):

Correct syntax is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".flip").click(function(){
    $("#panel").slideToggle("slow", complete);

    function complete(){alert("hello");}
  });
});
```

`[]` are used just to denote that the argument is optional.

Answer (score 1):

You can also directly include a function as a statement:

```
$("#panel").slideToggle("slow", function() {
    // things to happen AFTER the slide is finished
    })
);
```